# Kubernetes pod ID

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes ReplicaSet with 5 replicas. I want to have a pod ID which does increase for each replica, however it should not increase when a pod is recreating because it crashed.

Example:

```
 * ReplicaSet starts with 4 replicas    *
 * Replica 1 starts with the ID 1       *
 * Replica 2 starts with the ID 2       *
 * Replica 3 starts with the ID 3       *
 * Replica 4 starts with the ID 4       *
 * Replica 3 dies                       *
 * Replica 5(3) starts with ID 3        *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a Statefulset

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

Naming starts with ID 0, but that's somewhat the behavior you are looking for.

---

Answering your comment. When my SatefulSet uses an image I would build myself, I may use something like this, resolving my container index, before I would start my application:

```
if test -z "$HOSTNAME"; then
    HOSTNAME=`hostname 2>/dev/null`
fi
if echo "$HOSTNAME" | grep -E '.*-[0-9][0-9]*' >/dev/null ; then
    POD_IDX=`echo "$HOSTNAME" | sed 's|.*-\([0-9]*\)$|\1|'`
fi
#echo My index is $POD_IDX
```

In other cases, I may deploy an image from a public registry. Then, I would figure out a way to pass this application with a configuration contextualized by some initContainer, for example with Prometheus - which is not using a Pod index, though it could have re-used the block from above, ...:

```
  initContainers:
  - args:
    - -c
    - |
         set -x; \
         sed "/external_labels:.*/ascrape_by: $REPLICA" /etc/prometheus.yml.tpl | \
             sed "s|^scrape_by:|    scrape_by:|" >/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml;
    command: [ /bin/sh ]
    env:
    - name: REPLICA
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    image: docker.io/prom/prometheus:xx
```

Comment: can I also access the ID though metadata? (so I can add it into the env)

Comment: Not really. When dealing with my own image, I would add something in my entrypoint, that would check for container hostname, extract the numeric part if I do find one. In other cases, I may implement this in some initContainer, such as my main image would start with a configuration taking that index into consideration